# Why do I have to export my browser every time I launch jupyter notebook for it to work?

Tags: python, browser, terminal, jupyter-notebook, launch

If I just use the command

jupyter notebook

in terminal, my jupyter notebook will not launch. I must use the following command:

export BROWSER=/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome

to make it work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is to put

```
export BROWSER=/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome
```

expression into `~/.bash_profile` file.

Other option is to run jupyter command with `--no-browser` flag and go to the URI directly from the browser yourself.

Comment: This didn't fix the problem